# SQL Server 2012 Setup Failed - Requires .NET 4

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I have installed sql server 2012 but was unable to install **SQL Server Data Tools** and **Management Studio**. It seems to require the visual studio 2010 setup which I do not have with me. 
I have installed VS 2010 SP1 though, however it still seems to require setup though to install .net 4 which is also already installed. See below figure:
[image]

ALso see below I have **.NET 4** already installed:
[image]

Appreciate if someone can assist me in this problem I am having to install Data Tools and Management studio.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's seem like a resolution for sql server 2012 RC0 but try the solution mentioned in the last comment

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/712945/sql-2012-rc0-install-fails-with-net-4-0-error

It is mentioned there that

Hi Rick, this is a known issue that is due to the fact that you have a pre-release version of .Net 4.5 installed on the system.

In order to work around this issue, you can perform the following:

Here are the commands to run to force Denali setup to skip the installation of the .Net updates (note that on a 64-bit machine you need to create these in the 64-bit registry):

reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended\KB2544514" /v ThisVersionInstalled /t REG_SZ /d "Y"

reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Updates\Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Extended\KB2468871" /v ThisVersionInstalled /t REG_SZ /d "Y"

Let us know if this doesn't resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Kamran. I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: Ok. It managed to install Management studio but same error again with Sql server data tools.

Comment: Ok check the http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2867fe21-6414-4bd9-879e-ded00716ba70/problem-installing-sql-server-2012-windows-7-64-bit?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade

Comment by Mohammed Al-BasriArab Banking Corporation which is accepted as answer

Answer (score 0):

Install the .NET Framework 4.0 Language Pack first, and .NET Framework 3.5, from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=3324).